# React Native - passing function that uses a prop, - as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

If i have a function that i want to send to a component as a prop

```
// Bind the function
this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this)

// Create the function
myFunc(X) {
 this.props.anotherFunc(X).result === 'Something' && .....
}

// Pass the function as prop
<OtherComponent myFunc={this.myFunc} />
```

However the function is already using a prop from another class, and i get "cannot read property 'result' of undefined"

So how can i pass a function as a prop if that function is already using another prop from another component ?

Comment: Take a look here to find out more how you can pass `props` between `parent, child and siblings`: https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf . You can take the approach of using the new context API from React as describe in this post.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `render props` [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), its  is a technique for `sharing code` between react component `using props whose value is a function`. Another method is `Higher order component`.